# Opera не проигрывает html5 audio mp3 локально

Tags: javascript, html5, opera, web-audio

Сегодня неожиданно для себя заметил, что Опера перестала вопсроизводить html5 audio (mp3-файл) локально. То есть если выгрузить код и мп3-файл на сервер, то она воспроизводит нормально, но при открытии этого же html-файла с тегом audio и ссылкой локально, уже не работает. 
То есть такой код (к примеру):

```
<audio src="assets/test.mp3" controls></audio>
```

На сервере работает без проблем, локально на компьютере не воспроизводит. Кто знает, в чем причина? Неужели cors? В том же Хроме работает без проблем и локально, и на сервере.

Comment: А вы просто открываете html-файл в браузере, или запускаете локальный сервер?

Comment: Просто открываю html в браузере, естессно. Если разверну локальный сервак, то будет тот же эффект, что и с сайта. А интересно все же, почему не работает локально, работало раньше, и в Хроме работает. Я понимаю там, что xhr-запросы не проходят при локальном открытии из-за CORS, но обычная музыка...

Comment: Попробовал, но толку ожидаемо никакого. 
Проблема в том, что сам файл оно находит, иначе выбрасывает 404 в консоль. Но играть - не играет. При попытке запустить насильно через js (.play() ) выбрасывает ошибку "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.". Это какой-то конкретный баг Оперы, в Хроме такого нет. Вот я и думаю, мож есть настройка какая-то хитрая, потому что бред же.

Comment: Потому что нужно указывать source. Код в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Хм. Действительно работает. Весьма интересно, в чем причина. С сервера работает без всяких source. В Хроме работает и локально, и с сервера, а вдруг конкретно в Опере и конкретно локально нужен source, да еще и с указанием типа (без него не работает). 

Это весьма занимательно, но как теперь создать такой элемент из js? Через new Audio() не сработает, нужно new Source что ли делать и аппендить в Аудио, с указанием типа?

Comment: Это, видимо, особенность работы вебкита c локальными файлами.

Comment: А Хром разве не Вебкит?

Comment: @IliaSharapov они все blink, если быть более точным. И действительно, это какая-то странная проблема. Думаю, стоит написать об этом в баг-трекер оперы.

Comment: Опере написал об этом баге. Спасибо вам за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот можно создать на js такую конструкцию (вдруг пригодится кому-то):

```
var alarmSound = new Audio();
var alarmsource = document.createElement('source');
alarmsource.src='test.mp3';
alarmsource.type='audio/mpeg';
alarmSound.appendChild(alarmsource);
```

Но поведение весьма странное.